# How to use class style components in nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I setup a nuxt3 project. and I want to use class style components but when I am installing `vue-property-decorator`, I am getting below error. Can anyone have idea how to solve this and how can we use class based components in nuxt3.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look around and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: I'm not sure but AFAIK, class are per-se not the recommended way to go since we now have Composables.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a typical issue with legacy peer dependencies. You can circumvent that issue by passing `--legacy-peer-deps` to your npm command, e.g.:

```
npm i vue-property-decorator --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: He could also try with `yarn`, usually more verbose and less issues than NPM.